# WSO2 enterprise integrator, adding header to backend request

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've just started looking at WSO2 enterprise integrator.
I'm currently stuck when I'm trying to create an API which calls a backend service which requires authentication.

I'm currently stuck trying to add a simple header which its suppose to send to the backend as it needs authentication to access it.

I'm using their eclipse tooling and my XML currently looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <api context="/one" name="singleRestApi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
        <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Basic ZWNYGWRtaH42Q2xvdGRBZG1pbjmeMw=="/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="repos"/>
        </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Currently following the integration tutorials: [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Exposing+Several+Services+as+a+Single+Service)

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What issue are you facing with this API? You can use header mediator or define 'Authorization' header property as described in http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-add-http-basic-authentication.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to put your Authorization in a property instead of an header (if you want to do a simple basic authentication)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <api context="/one" name="singleRestApi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
        <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Basic ZWNYGWRtaH42Q2xvdGRBZG1pbjmeMw=="/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="repos"/>
        </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

the `<property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>`
part is to remove the api context (after /one) when sending to your backend endpoint, if you need to keep it you can remove this line